# VB.NET - Label Text

Tags: vb.net

How would I make a label have a 'variable' (the NumericUpDown), and then add text after it. So it would be like "7 Seconds"

```
Label2.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value "Text"
```

Above is my code

[Question Revised cause I was ban from questions...]

Comment: `Label2.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString` might do what you want. I have no idea what "and text (Seconds) would be 20 Seconds." means

Comment: can you clarify what you need? what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `ToString` method on the Value property. The `&` operator concatenates the two strings together.

```
Label2.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString & " Seconds"
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are always multiple ways to accomplish a task. My first instinct would have been to use the Convert function...

```
Label2.Text = CStr(NumericUpDown1.Value) & " Seconds"
```